# Virtual functions, class templates overriding them and incomplete types

Tags: c++

Let's consider the following code snippet (spread across several files):

Base.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual void foo () = 0;
};

template <class D>
class BaseImpl : public Base
{
public:
  BaseImpl () : d (new D ()) {}
  virtual ~BaseImpl () { delete d; }
  void foo () override;
private:
  D * d;
};

template <class D>
void BaseImpl <D>::foo ()
{
  std::cout << d->value << std::endl;
}
```

Derived.h:

```
#include "Base.h"

struct Data;

class Derived : public BaseImpl <Data>
{
public:
  Derived ();
  ~Derived ();
};
```

Derived.cpp:

```
#include "Derived.h"

struct Data
{
  int value = 123;
};

Derived::Derived () {}
Derived::~Derived () {}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Derived.h"

int main ()
{
    Derived d;

    d.foo (); // [1] error
    ((Base *) & d)->foo (); // [2] fine
}
```

This example produces a compiler error on CLang (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5) at line [1] as following:

> ```
> g++ -c -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o
> In file included from main.cpp:1:
> In file included from ./Derived.h:1:
> ./Base.h:22:17: error: member access into incomplete type 'Data'
>   std::cout << d->value << std::endl;
>                 ^
> main.cpp:7:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'BaseImpl<Data>::foo' requested here
>   d.foo (); // [1]
>     ^
> ./Derived.h:3:8: note: forward declaration of 'Data'
> struct Data;
>        ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

A similar error is generated by gcc 4.9.2:

> ```
> g++ -c -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o
> In file included from Derived.h:1:0,
>                  from main.cpp:1:
> Base.h: In instantiation of 'void BaseImpl<D>::foo() [with D = Data]':
> main.cpp:7:10:   required from here
> Base.h:22:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Data'
>    std::cout << d->value << std::endl;
>              ^
> In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
> Derived.h:3:8: error: forward declaration of 'struct Data'
>  struct Data;
>         ^
> ```

Interesting enough, if line [1] is commented out, everything builds (and works) fine and line [2] doesn't produce any compiler errors. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

The error at [1] expectedly goes away if the forward declaration of `Data` in `Derived.h` is replaced with its full definition from `Derived.cpp` but the intention is to make it hidden from users of `Derived` because it is implementation detail (see also below).

For those curious (and familiar with Qt), in real life `Base` is `QAbstractItemModel`, `BaseImpl` is a class template whose purpose is to provide real storage for model items and implement `QAbstractItemModel` (pure) virtual functions. `Derived` is merely an alias for `BaseImpl` implementing a particular data model and `Data` is what is used internally by this model to store each item's data so it should be separate from `Derived` and hidden from code using the final model class.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186469/discussion-on-question-by-truedmik-virtual-functions-class-templates-overriding).

Answer (score 0):

The example program is ill-formed.

To start with, the definition of any template is checked for valid syntax like all other code, but a C++ implementation is not required to check the semantics of any parts that depend on a template parameter unless/until that template is instantiated. (An implementation may report a semantic error even without any instantiations if there are no possible template arguments that would make a specialization valid.)

So the program is fine if the translation unit resulting from main.cpp does not instantiate the function template specialization `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()`. But when exactly is this template specialization instantiated? [[temp.inst]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#inst-3) says:

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program.

The main requirement that a definition exists comes from the ODR rule, [[basic.def.odr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#10):

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required.... An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used outside of a discarded statement.

Here it doesn't matter whether we say the specialization `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()` is "inline" or not. Both flavors of the ODR rule end up saying that if the specialization is odr-used, then it must be defined (in some way or another), which means the specialization is implicitly instantiated.

There are different definitions of the technical term "odr-use" for different sorts of entities (and sometimes those definitions overlap).  Quoting a bit more than necessary from [basic.def.odr]/5-8 to make a point:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is *odr-used* by `ex` unless....
>
> A structured binding is odr-used if it appears as a potentially-evaluated expression.
>
> `*this` is odr-used if `this` appears as a potentially-evaluated expression (including as the result of the implicit transformation in the body of a non-static member function).
>
> A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure. A function is odr-used if it is named by a potentially-evaluated expression. A non-placement allocation or deallocation function for a class is odr-used by the definition of a constructor of that class. A non-placement deallocation function for a class is odr-used by the definition of the destructor of that class, or by being selected by the lookup at the point of definition of a virtual destructor.
>
> An assignment operator function in a class is odr-used by an implicitly-defined copy-assignment or move-assignment function for another class as specified in [class.copy.assign]. A constructor for a class is odr-used as specified in [dcl.init]. A destructor for a class is odr-used if it is potentially invoked.

Note all of these definitions for "odr-used" associate the property to some specific expression or definition, *except* the one saying a virtual function that is not pure is odr-used just by existing.  So in most cases, implicit instantiation happens because of these specific other expressions and definitions which require the template specialization.  What this means in terms of instantiating a virtual function is somewhat clarified in [[temp.inst]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.inst#10) and [[temp.point]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.point#5):

> It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.
>
> If a virtual function is implicitly instantiated, its point of instantiation is immediately following the point of instantiation of its enclosing class template specialization.

So if your main.cpp never mentioned `foo` at all, but it still required the instantiation of class `BaseImpl<Data>` while `Data` is still an incomplete type, it would be unspecified whether or not the program is valid!  So even that's probably not a good idea.

Incidentally though, this is why the translation unit from Derived.cpp is allowed to instantiate `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()`.  And g++, along with most compilers that use the common "vtable" strategy for virtual functions, will instantiate any needed class template members which are the final overrides for a class whenever any constructor for that class is (explicitly or implicitly) defined, since it needs to build a vtable which includes those functions so the constructor can set the class object's internal vptr to point at the vtable.

But I said at the start it's ill-formed, because of the other piece implied by "would not otherwise be instantiated".  The other sentence which could imply `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()` is odr-used was "A function is odr-used if it is named by a potentially-evaluated expression".  Backing up shortly before that quote, we find that "function named by an expression" is also a technical definition, in [[basic.def.odr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#3):

> A function is *named by an expression* as follows:
>
> - A function whose name appears in an expression is named by that expression if it is the unique lookup result or the selected member of a set of overloaded functions ([basic.lookup], [over.match], [over.over]), unless it is a pure virtual function and either its name is not explicitly qualified or the expression forms a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]).
> - ...

Now the expression `d.foo()` does a lookup for a member `foo` in `Derived`, and the unique result is `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()`.  Since it's not pure virtual, `d.foo()` *names* `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()`.  The expression `((Base *) & d)->foo()` does a lookup for a member `foo` in `Base`, and the unique result is `Base::foo()`.  Since `Base::foo()` is pure virtual and the name `foo` is unqualified in the expression, `((Base *) & d)->foo()` does not name any function.

I'm sure you know those two expressions (if the program were changed to be valid) would actually call the same function.  But the way polymorphism is described in the C++ Standard is that the function which is *named* is not always the same as the function which is *called*.  This distinction is also important for other reasons - like the member access checks apply to the named function, not the called function, and the default arguments associated with declarations of the named function, not the called function, are available for use.  It just happens that here's another tricky difference that comes up depending on the actual function named.

Anyway, to tie it up, the expression `d.foo()` in main.cpp odr-uses `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()`, which means an implicit instantation of `BaseImpl<Data>::foo()`.  Since `d` points at an object of incomplete class type `Data`, the expression `d->value` in the definition of this instantiated specialization is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! Makes sense, but I see a few weak spots in your logic. 1) your referring to pure virtual doesn't actually matter because if I make `Base::foo()` non-pure, the result is completely the same. So there must be something else. 2) `Derived.cpp` knows `Data` so it can legally instantiate everything. I can agree to your bottom line though. In the sense that [1] performs a lookup in `BaseImpl<Data>` w/o involving vtable since the compiler knows `d` is a `BaseImpl<Data>` instance. Sort of an optimization as I see it. I'd like to disable it in this particular case...